# How to get comments and likes for public post which mentions a fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am querying the fql stream table to get all the posts for a fan page. One of the post on the page wall is a post which was written on user's wall but had the page mentioned in it.

Example: http://www.facebook.com/jeff.judge/posts/10150356144351153

The post id returned in fql response for this post is 156834651009457_271264652899789. Now if I query the stream table for this post_id, I am getting back empty array for comments and likes. How do I correctly  fetch the comments and likes for this post? It is a public post, so I am guessing I should be able to get the comment/likes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the comments list is empty, but there is a way to get the list populated. Concatenate the `actor_id` with the post "id" used on the wall:

```
612846152_10150356144351153
```

And query for that `post_id` instead.

Comment: I'd be extremely interested in knowing why the first post_id doesn't work and why the second one does.